# Int to byte array and back doesnt give the same value on big numbers

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I'm trying to convert an int to an byte array and then do base64 to create a blockId for Azure Rest API. I've gotten the first bit correct, the when where I convert the int to a base64 string:

```
int a = 127;
int b = 4000;
```

C#:

```
byte[] blockIdBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
string blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(blockIdBytes);
```

`a` gives "fwAAAA==" and `b` gives "oA8AAA=="

C++

```
QByteArray temp;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++) {
    temp.append((char)(a >> (i * 8)));
}
```

`a` gives "fwAAAA==" and `b` gives "oA8AAA==" (same values as above, which is correct)

Now the issue is, when I try to convert the base64-string back to an int? My bytearray to int method does not work on numbers bigger than 127, why?

```
int result = 0;

for(int i = temp.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    result = (result << 8) + temp[i];
}
```

127 works but when I do 128 (for example) the result is "-128". I realize the it overflows, but why and where?

EDIT:

Tried:

```
QByteArray temp;
int a = 340;

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++) {
  temp.append((unsigned char)(a >> (i * 8)));
}
```

Which actaully gives "340" when I convert it back, "255" gives "-1" and "256" gives "256"

Comment: because you're casting as a signed char when you append to "temp". A byte is the equivalent of an UNSIGNED char. (range 0-255) rather than a signed char (range -127 to 127) `for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++) {
    temp.append((unsigned char)(a >> (i * 8)));
}
`

Comment: still getting the same issue even when I changed that

Comment: In the second-to-last code block where you loop from temp.size() to zero, how are you able to dereference the array at position temp.size()?  If the array is of size 8, then temp[7] is the last element of the array, no?

Comment: `result = (result << 8) + ((int)(temp[i]) & 0xFF)`; try this while converting back

Comment: @ds1848 oh snap. nicly spotted. thank you for that. no idea how it worked after the fix :p

Comment: @keety that worked perfectly. could you please explain why and why i couldnt just use the code snippets that i found that worked for other people? im am happy to accept your answer if you make it to a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are converting back you need to treat all the values in temp[i] as `unsigned char` 
 or ignore the signed bit  . In the below code snippet you end up promoting temp[i] to integer then explicitly we reset the signed bit if any to 0 making it positive

`result = (result << 8) + ((int)(temp[i]) & 0xFF)`

you should be able to achieve the same using

`result = (result << 8) + ((unsigned char)(temp[i]))`